# Title span two lines then ellipses, instead of one line

Tags: css

I'd like to have the title text on my video thumbnails go across 2 lines, and then ellipses if it's too long past that point. Exactly like Youtube do it:

```
TEENAGE MUTANT NINJA 
TURTLES - Official Traile…
```

Like that.

At the moment, mines like this:

```
TEENAGE MUTANT NINJA TUR…
```

My current class is:

```
#sidebar .menu .link .title {
  margin-left: 15px;
  cursor: pointer;
  display: block;
  font-size: 12px;
  line-height: 34px;
  display: inline;
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
}
```

And HTML like so:

```
<p class="title"><a title="Title of video is really long, heaps cool" href="#">Title of video is really long, heaps cool</a></p>
```

I've tried copying what Youtube have using Firebug, but I couldn't figure out how to get it to work.

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is the [codepen link](http://codepen.io/chriscoyier/pen/iBtep)

CSS-Tricks have given a wide range of examples of different cool ways to achieve what you want and explained it well.
You can check them here --> http://css-tricks.com/line-clampin/